# why q_enum unable to get correct type value without qRegisterMetaType?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qmetatype

I have a QT project with several dlls.

Dlls:  A, B, C

A depends on B and C. While B and C doesn't have any dependencies.

B exports custom class B_Custom.  Class B_Custom is derived from QObject.

Dll A:

```
Class Exported A : public C
{
    ...
    Q_PROPERTY(B_Custom:B_Enum b_enum READ GetBEnum WRITE SetBEnum NOTIFY BEnumChanged);

    void DoSomething()
    {
        SomethingElse("b_enum");
    }

    ....
}
```

Dll B:

```
class Exported B_Custom: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT;
    public:
        enum B_Enum {
            ...
        };
        Q_ENUM(B_Enum);
    ...
}
```

Dll C:

```
Class C : public QObject
{
    virtual void SomethingElse(const QByteArray &propName)
    {
        auto type = property(propName).userType();
    }
}
```

In main:

```
A * a = new A();
a->DoSomething();
```

The problem is for Class C, the type value of function SomethingElse is QMetaType::UnknownType.

But if I manually register the B_Enum in Dll B with

```
qRegisterMetaType<B_Custom::B_Enum>()
```

before call A::DoSomething(), 
the type value of function SomethingElse will not be QMetaType::UnknownType.

It will return correct type value like 1230 for type in function SomethingElse of class C.

But accroding to QT document @http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM,

Enumerations that are declared with Q_ENUM have their QMetaEnum registered in the enclosing QMetaObject. 
You can also use QMetaEnum::fromType() to get the QMetaEnum.

Registered enumerations are automatically registered also to the Qt meta type system, making them known to QMetaType without the need to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE().

So why I need to call qRegisterMetaType() in order to let type in SomethingElse function of Class C get correct type value?

There are quit a lot similar types in dll B and need to get type information in class C.

If I need to use qRegisterMetaType to register these types one by one, its really not a pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carefully look into below documentation:

**"Also, to use type T with the QObject::property() API, qRegisterMetaType() must be called before it is used, typically in the constructor of the class that uses T, or in the main() function."**

This is mentioned in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1.

Now coming back to your code:

you declared `Q_ENUM(B_Enum);` in class `B_Custom`.

But the property for that `enum` is declared in `class A`.

Now again look back to the documentation statement above specified.

So, to use the `enum` with the `property` declared in `class A`, either you have to register the meta type in the `class A` constructor or in the main function before using it (which you did and working).

***More over you may get a doubt, why we need to register again in a different class.***

Look into below statement: It seems you have to register the type in all the classes, where ever you are using, not just in the class where you declared.

**"Had the enumeration type been declared in another class, its fully qualified name (i.e., OtherClass::Priority) would be required, and that other class would also have to inherit QObject and register the enumeration type there using the Q_ENUM() macro."** (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html)

Comment: But the doc ([link]http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) said that other class would also have to inherit QObject and register the enumeration type there using the Q_ENUM() macro.
In Class B, it is inherit QObject and registered the enum B_Enum  using Q_Enum macro.
If we need to use qRegisterMetaType again everywhere we use the enum, it is not a good design.  
Shouldn't qt already implement some mechanism to auto register this kind of enums?

Comment: My guess is ...in this way .... I mean restricting to a class level....is to stick to encapsulation.. private remains private

Comment: For my case, all I know in SomethingElse function is the property name.
Is there way to retrieve the type of the property at runtime and use qRegisterMetaType to register the type at runtime?

Comment: use QObject::property(const char *name); Pass the property name as input. It returns QVariant object.And query about type using "Type()"  function of QVariant and register it.

Comment: katamarayudu, thanks for the suggestion.

But unfortunately,  QObject::property(const char *name) will return a invalid value of QVariant since the property type is not registered. 

Seems like except use  qRegisterMetaType to register the enum type explicitly, there's no other way to solve it.

I just can't believe qt doesn't have an automatic solution to auto register the enum which used in Q_PROPERTY.